# How to automatically create links to C++ classes in markdown using doxygen?

Tags: c++, markdown, doxygen

I am working on C++11 project, and we use Doxygen to create nice html API documentation.

I noticed that when I write class name directly in `hpp` files, doxygen generates links to corresponding class.

But when I write same class name in *.md files, links are not generated.

Do I need to enable this in config or use special syntax to enable links?

Comment: have a look at the`\link`, `\ref` commands

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate links automatically when I replaced markdown code block with `<code><pre>...</pre></code>`:

````
  // link to MyClass is not generated
  \```C++
  Doc is about MyClass...
  \```

    |
    v

  // link to MyClass is generated
  <code>
    <pre>
  Doc is about MyClass...
    </pre>
  </code>
````

UPD: added backslash so that they are properly rendered on StackOverflow.

Comment: the construct with the backslash and the (3) backticks is a bit strange, this should just be 3 backticks. End of the code block `<code>` should be `</code>`. When I try the code I do see all links to `MyClass`. Why are you using `<pre>` inside the `<code>` block? Which version of doxygen are you using, What is the name of your markdown file? Note also that `C++` should be `cpp`.

Comment: Doxygen version is 1.8.18, file name is `introduction.md`. <pre> is used for code blocks.